# Problem opening VCF files on tf300

Tags: vcard

I am trying to help my Father debug an issue he has on the TF300 since it upgraded to Jelly Bean.  We are both unable to open a vCard file from email or from Astro file explorer. It appears to the user that nothing happens when he hits view in Gmail. He receives vCard emails all of the time from his work.  I can save it, open "people" and then import it, but I cannot import it from Gmail view it.  We can open it from Gmail on Jelly Bean on both my Galaxy Nexus and my Nexus 7.

This sounds like a file association issue, but there are no defaults under Contacts.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to debug this?  Is there an easy  way without USB debugging to determine what program gets called?

Edit: 
   What is the easiest way to log every process opened after a file is clicked on?  I am happy to use USB debugging at this point.

Comment: Not sure if that works in your case, but it's worth a try: [VCard Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/vcard-manager-vcard-sms/net.hsrco.vcardmanager) claims to be able to open all types of VCards. Also, there's [Contacts VCF](http://www.appbrain.com/app/contacts-vcf/by.androld.contactsvcf) which says to open any `.vcf` file.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, and glad the issue solved for you! I summed things up in an answer (including your final solution) for other possibly affected people which might not be that lucky with an OS upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case an OS upgrade solved the issue.

For someone in a similar situation without an OS upgrade (or other fix) in sight, it might be worth taking a look at [VCard Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/vcard-manager-vcard-sms/net.hsrco.vcardmanager) (which claims to be able to open all types of VCards) or [Contacts VCF](http://www.appbrain.com/app/contacts-vcf/by.androld.contactsvcf), which says to open any `.vcf` file:

[image: VCard Manager] [image: Contacts VCF]
<sup>*VCard Manager* and *Contacts VCF* (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>